# How to show ArrayList variable in JSP index page

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

In my servlet page I fetched data from database and store it in a ArrayList. I want to pass the ArrayList in the index(jsp) page and want to show the value of ArrayList inside the iframe tag; which was fetched from database.

I want to show the variables of arrayList (which was fetched from database, url of some website) inside the iframe tag of index page .....

Comment: use `<% java code %>` . u can use this tag inside jsp.

Comment: it's not working .....@SandunChathuranga

Comment: `<%=ArrayListName.get(1)%>` try this inside `<p>` tag

Comment: in jsp page tha value showing is null.............that means the ArrayList is not passed to the index page from servlet page ......@SandunChathuranga

Comment: Please add your code so that we can see what you are seeing. Otherwise, no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: try
        {
            con=new monitoring.db.DBConnect().getCon();
            String query="select * from website where id=2";
            ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
           while(rs.next())
           {al.add(rs.getString("url_name"));}                   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("website_details", al);
            
             //response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                 request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                 
                }

Comment: rephrase the title and add relevant tag

Answer (score 0):

In servlet store the arraylist session name **`arrList`**

```
session.setAttribute("arrList", arrList);
```

In JSP trying to access arrList session **(inside head tag)**

```
<%if(session.getAttribute("arrList")!=null){
        ArrayList<String> arrList = (ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("arrList");
} %>
```

using forloop get value of array list

```
<% for(int i=0; i<arrList.size(); i++){ %>
<P> <%=arrListget(i)%> </P>
<% } %>
```

Comment: It shows session.getAttribute(" ") = null.........                                                                   The session value is not passed frm servlet to jsp page ...how to do it ?

Comment: before redirect to JSP you should store values to session. did you get that?

to get idea about session follow this link. 

http://www.javatpoint.com/http-session-in-session-tracking

Comment: This is my code .....                                                                                   .HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("website_details", al);
             response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");                                                          ...........@Sandun

Comment: `ArrayList<String> arrList=(ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("website_details");` inside jsp?

Comment: Yes I write same as it is inside head tag in jsp page ...and want to show the variable of ("website_details") inside the  iframe tag in the jsp page ......         <iframe src="<% al1.get(1);  %>" class="preview"></iframe>   .............but thats not working

Comment: `src="<%= al1.get(1) %>"` try this

Comment: Its not working.The problem is that the value of al1 in index page is showing null. The value of arrayList is not successfully passed from servlet page to jsp page.Hence it shows null ponter Exception at index page at line ....<iframe src="<%= al1.get(1)  %>" class="preview"></iframe> ....@Sandun